# Group ring of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, laurent-series, group-rings

We know that the group ring $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z]$ of $\mathbb Z$ is just the Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[t^{\pm1}]$. I want to know about the group ring $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z]$ of the direct product $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, does it have a similar description? Is it a Laurent polynomial in two variables $s$ and $t$ : $\mathbb Z[s^{\pm 1},t^{\pm 1}]$ ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. The group ring functor sends finite direct products to tensor products.

Comment: Have you tried to write down an explicit, nice function between the two, and then tried to show that it is a homomorphism and an isomorphism? It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Is it the map that sends each $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}a_i(n_i,m_i)\in \mathbb Z[\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z]$ to the polynomial $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}a_is^{n_i}t^{m_i}$?

Comment: Is your map a ring homomorphism ? Surjective ? Injective ?